# Why are local submersions and local immersions not studied in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds?

Tags: soft-question, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

I'm reading through Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* and wondered why local submersions or local immersions are not studied.

---

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds (with or without boundary) and let $F:M\to N$ be a smooth map between them.

**Definition:** if any point $p\in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $F(U)$ is open and $F|_U$ is a diffeomorphism, submersion, or immersion, then we call $F$ a ***local diffeomorphism***, ***local submersion***, or ***local immersion***, respectively.

Local diffeomorphisms are properly studied in the book, but local submersions and local immersions are not present. **Why is this so?**

Comment: Submersion is the same as local submersion. For local immersion if tou drop the openness condition it is the same as immersion. Local diffeomorphism is not the same as diffeomorphism because of the extra global requirements of injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see. Why are local sub/immersions equivalent to sub/immersions?

Comment: Just look at the definition of submersion/immersion. The definition is that the “for each point, the tangent map is surjective/injective”. This is at the level of tangent spaces, meaning it only depends on arbitrarily small neighborhoods of the point in question. It doesn’t matter how big or small the domain of the map is.